# Smooth camera rotation in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, gl-matrix

I have implemented a simple version of a camera. It's only purpose is to look around the scene (which means only rotation).
Every frame I update then the `mat4.lookAt` and `mat4.perspective` ([javascript math library](http://glmatrix.net/)), but on mobile (f.e. android), the move arounds feels laggy.
This is how i calculate `yaw` and `pitch`:

```
rotate(ev) {
    let xOffSet = ev.center.x - this._lastX;
    let YOffSet = this._lastY - ev.center.y;

    this._lastX = ev.center.x;
    this._lastY = ev.center.y;

    let sensitivity = 0.005;
    xOffSet *= sensitivity;
    YOffSet *= sensitivity;

    this._yaw += xOffSet;
    this._pitch += YOffSet;
}
```

and with the updated `yaw` and `pitch` I recalculate the `matrices`:

```
updateViewProjMatrix() {
    let gl = Core.mGetGL();
    this._frontVector[0] = Math.cos(this._yaw) * Math.cos(this._pitch);
    this._frontVector[1] = Math.sin(this._pitch);
    this._frontVector[2] = Math.sin(this._yaw) * Math.cos(this._pitch);

    vec3.normalize(this._lookAtVector, this._frontVector);
    vec3.add(this._lookAtVector, this._lookAtVector, this._positionVector);

    mat4.lookAt(this._viewMatrix, this._positionVector, this._lookAtVector, this._upVector);
    mat4.perspective(this._projMatrix, this._fov * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, this._nearPlane, this._farPlane);
    mat4.multiply(this._vpMatrix, this._projMatrix, this._viewMatrix);
}
```

Is there a way I can improve my camera? Or would you do something completey different? If so what would you change?

Comment: Do you update your view in the requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: Yes , I have a render function, which calls requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Try multiplying your `offset` by time passed from previous frame.

Comment: Ok i will try this. Will update my questions if this works

Comment: How's FPS of your application? Maybe that's the issue.